# Laurent series 0 < |z-3| < 3

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, series-expansion

I wanna check my laurent series exercises on Mathematica, but can't seem to find a command or program to achieve the result of such type of interval.

$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-3) z},\\1<|z-3|<3$

The command Series[] won't let me use $z-3$ as the expansion variable.

Comment: Please, look at the following reference:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23578/laurent-series-expansion?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to expand your series about the point z = 3 you can do this:

```
Series[1/(z - 3)/z, {z, 3, n}]
```

Just change `n` to be the number of terms you want in the expansion.

Comment: You can use `SeriesCoefficient` too and not need to replace `n` with an explicit integer.

Comment: But wouldn't it be the same as calculate the series for 0 < |z| <3?