# How to calculate Laurent series in mathematica about some point zo and annulus a<|z|<b?

Tags: series-expansion

Can sameone tell me how to calculate Laurent series in mathematica about some point and annulus?

Comment: There's already an answer to this if you just search for Laurent Series: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23578/laurent-series-expansion and here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129043/laurent-series-0-z-3-3?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: See (18) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentSeries.html to this end.